# BleGattCharacteristicException status 0x06 when reading Ble characteristic

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I'm using RxAndroidBle library for communicating with bluetooth device, 
however recently i bumped into strange issue. 
When reading one of the device characteristics i receive such error:

```
BleGattCharacteristicException{macAddress=60:CE:32:BA:9E:70, 
 status=6 (0x06 -> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.0_r1/stack/include/gatt_api.h), 
 bleGattOperationType=BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}}
```

I see that the description states that something is wrong with the characteristic read but I was able to read it on the same device using some commercial scanners or vanilla bluetooth code from google samples. 
I checked the characteristic properties - it has PROPERTY_READ.

I bump into same error when using Polidea sample of RxAndroidBle.

Couldn't find similar case anywhere in the internet, maybe someone bumped into such error. 
Additional info might be that the device I'm connecting to is a ble device simulator running on an iPhone. 
I'm not providing any snippets as I'm using the same code which is in the core examples.

Full verbose log:

```
06-12 11:00:20.105 22459-22459/? D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationConnect(121589482)
06-12 11:00:20.106 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationConnect(121589482)
06-12 11:00:20.131 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50, auto: false
06-12 11:00:20.131 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
06-12 11:00:20.131 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=b6c1ef8f-408b-4afb-8e27-97a6ff2c20fb
06-12 11:00:20.137 22459-22473/? D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
06-12 11:00:20.330 22459-22473/? D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50
06-12 11:00:20.333 22459-22473/? D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onConnectionStateChange newState=2 status=0
06-12 11:00:20.395 22459-22854/? D/CharacteristicOperationExampleActivity: Hey, connection has been established!
06-12 11:00:20.400 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationConnect(121589482)
06-12 11:00:25.608 22459-22459/? I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
06-12 11:00:25.663 22459-22459/? I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
06-12 11:00:25.675 22459-22459/? D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover(3295555)
06-12 11:00:25.676 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover(3295555)
06-12 11:00:25.683 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50
06-12 11:00:25.726 22459-22473/? D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50 Status=0
06-12 11:00:25.727 22459-22473/? D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onServicesDiscovered status=0
06-12 11:00:25.732 22459-22854/? D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(177013014)
06-12 11:00:25.733 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationServicesDiscover(3295555)
06-12 11:00:25.735 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(177013014)
06-12 11:00:25.827 22459-22471/? W/BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicRead() - Device=41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50 handle=102 Status=6
06-12 11:00:25.830 22459-22471/? D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicRead characteristic=1f26b1a4-2b50-11e7-99a8-fcaa142b0bea status=6
06-12 11:00:25.844 22459-22471/? D/RxBle#Radio:   QUEUED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(84936079)
06-12 11:00:25.849 22459-22471/? D/elo: error: BleGattCharacteristicException{macAddress=41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50, status=6 (0x06 -> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.0_r1/stack/include/gatt_api.h), bleGattOperationType=BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}}
06-12 11:00:25.879 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationCharacteristicRead(177013014)
06-12 11:00:25.880 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio:  STARTED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(84936079)
06-12 11:00:25.915 22459-22459/? D/elo: error: BleGattCharacteristicException{macAddress=41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50, status=6 (0x06 -> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-5.1.0_r1/stack/include/gatt_api.h), bleGattOperationType=BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}}
06-12 11:00:25.925 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothManager: getConnectionState()
06-12 11:00:25.925 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
06-12 11:00:25.951 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50
06-12 11:00:25.962 22459-22471/? D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=41:0A:AE:0E:C2:50
06-12 11:00:25.966 22459-22471/? D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onConnectionStateChange newState=0 status=0
06-12 11:00:25.971 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothGatt: close()
06-12 11:00:25.971 22459-22459/? D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=6
06-12 11:00:25.974 22459-22504/? D/RxBle#Radio: FINISHED RxBleRadioOperationDisconnect(84936079)
```

Verbose log from the Google Bluetooth Sample app in which I can read that property

```
06-12 14:43:36.540 10869-10869/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
06-12 14:43:36.598 10869-10869/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
06-12 14:43:36.599 10869-10869/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothLeService: Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.
06-12 14:43:41.209 10869-10869/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothAdapter: stopLeScan()
06-12 14:43:41.215 10869-10869/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothAdapter: scan not started yet
06-12 14:43:43.781 10869-10882/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=5F:56:F7:E9:8A:38
06-12 14:43:43.789 10869-10882/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt I/BluetoothLeService: Connected to GATT server.
06-12 14:43:43.789 10869-10882/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: 5F:56:F7:E9:8A:38
06-12 14:43:43.792 10869-10882/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt I/BluetoothLeService: Attempting to start service discovery:true
06-12 14:43:45.513 10869-10882/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=5F:56:F7:E9:8A:38 Status=0
06-12 14:43:54.958 10869-10869/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 1f26b1a4-2b50-11e7-99a8-fcaa142b0bea enable: true
06-12 14:43:55.063 10869-10882/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt W/BluetoothGatt: onCharacteristicRead() - Device=5F:56:F7:E9:8A:38 handle=110 Status=0
```

There is a difference indeed, as this app is setting a notification before reading a value. The code in app responsible for that looks like this:

```
// If a given GATT characteristic is selected, check for supported features.  This sample
    // demonstrates 'Read' and 'Notify' features.  See
    // http://d.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html for the complete
    // list of supported characteristic features.
    private final ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener servicesListClickListner =
            new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                            int childPosition, long id) {
                    if (mGattCharacteristics != null) {
                        final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                                mGattCharacteristics.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
                        final int charaProp = characteristic.getProperties();
                        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ) > 0) {
                            // If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
                            // it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
                            if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
                                mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                        mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
                                mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
                            }
                            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
                        }
                        if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                            mNotifyCharacteristic = characteristic;
                            mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(
                                    characteristic, true);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
    };
```

As for RxAndroidBle version, I tested it on 1.2.0, 1.2.4 and 1.3.0. 
Android versions 7.1, 6.0.1 and 5.1.

Will try to implement this notification before reading characteristic as it's the only difference I can see.

Comment: wow, i read the title as thought "what the hell is a BattleStarGalacticaException"

Comment: What Android OS version do you use? And what version of the library? Could you also paste logs from the vanilla Android implementation that works for comparison?

Comment: I've edited the question with the requested info

Comment: Registering notifications before performing read didn't help. I still receive the same error.

Comment: I've also removed this whole notification part from this working vanilla app and it didn't break it so i think it's a dead end.

Comment: Looks like a bug in either Android BLE stack or iOS implementation of the server. Have you tried to add some delay before sending the read request?

Comment: No i didn't, delay after what action?

Comment: Before sending the read request. After `RxBleConnection` is emitted. Maybe it would also be a good idea to use the `readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic)` function and add some delay between it and `.discoverServices()`.

Comment: @Jogosb Anything you could add?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. As for passing BluetoothGattCharacteristic instead of UUID - it didn't help, I've also tried to pass the characteristic retrieved by the getCharacteristic method and it also didn't solve the issue. What helped was the update of the simulator - guys added more characteristics to that particular service. I actually didn't have time to play with adding a delay (i need to make amends in the library, right?), but I'll surely try it as this error might occur again in the future. So maybe this info will be some kind of a hint for You.